# ElasticSearch filtering for a tag in array

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

I've got a bunch of events that are tagged for their audience:

```
{ id = 123, audiences = ["Public", "Lecture"], ... }
```

I've trying to do an ElasticSearch query with filtering, so that the search will only return events that have the an exact entry of "Public" in that audiences array (and won't return events that a "Not Public").

How do I do that?

This is what I have so far, but it's returning zero results, even though I definitely have "Public" events:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/events/event/_search' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : {
                    "audiences": "Public"
                }
            },
            "query" : {
                "match" : {
                    "title" : "[searchterm]" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2) for you content type

```
{
  "your_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "your_type": {
        "properties": {
          "audiences": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          },
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> *not_analyzed*
>   Index this field, so it is searchable, but index the
>   value exactly as specified. Do not analyze it.

And use lowercase term value in search query

Comment: Updating this answer based on changes in https://www.elastic.co/blog/strings-are-dead-long-live-strings from 07Sept2016. Instead of `string` and `not_analyzed`, as of ES5.0 you should use 
`{ "type": "keyword", "index": false }`